# Why are properties starting with '_' created automatically?

Tags: javascript, object

Shouldn't this raise an error since I haven't declared `this._name` as a property? Why is it automatically created?

p.s.***if this.name and this._name is a different property, shouldn't it print Tom/Tom/Tom since this.name naver been changed after declaration?

```js
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(value){
    this._name=value;
  }
  sayName(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
var person=new Person("Tom");//TOM
console.log(person.name);
person.name="Huck";
console.log(person.name);//Huck
person.sayName();//Huck
```

Comment: It *doesn't* create a property. The property `this._name` doesn't exist, before or after you try to access it, so it just returns `undefined`

Comment: Javascript is not a type safe language. It doesn't care if you try and access a property that doesn't exist. As above, it just returns `undefined` when you do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your constructor you set `this.name`, but the setter for `name` actually sets `_name`. So no, it's not being automatically created - it's normal behaviour for a JavaScript object to create that property when it doesn't already exist. Even if it already exists, the logic is the same - think about it. If you had an `if` statement to check if it existed or not, what would it look like? This:

```
if (this._name) this._name = value;
else this._name = value;
```

There's literally no difference in anything that happens, since accessing an undefined property returns `undefined` rather than throwing an error - if it helps, you can think that it exists, but is just `undefined`.

Comment: but if this.name and this._name is a different and new property when i set new name and call sayName it should print the original name, not the new one.
for example
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(value){
    this._name=value;
  }
  sayName(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
var person=new Person("Tom");
console.log(person.name);
person.name="Huck";
console.log(person.name);
person.sayName();

the printed log is Tom/Huck/Huck. but if name and _name is a different property

Comment: `this.name` is, the way you've defined it, an alias for `this._name`. They're pretty much identical as long as you interact solely with `this.name`.

Comment: oh, so i can access this.name by both this.name and this._name identically?

Comment: Accessing `this.name` accesses `this._name` behind the scenes, but not vice versa.